# Unmarshal with global namespace

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I have the following XML:

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    ...
    <item>
      <link>http://stackoverflow.com</link>
      <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="http://stackoverflow.com"/>
      ...
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I want to extract the `link` attribute, I have the following struct:

```
type Item struct {
  Link string `xml:"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom link"`
}
```

I know, that I need a prefix to get the Link, but  because there is no namespace given (in form of an `xmls`-Attribute, but I don't know, how.

I could, of course, save all `:*link`-Attributes to a slice, but I'm sure there is a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The namespace handling in Go's XML parser is a bit buggy, as you can see with this test program: http://play.golang.org/p/LgW-vm4euL.  And if I comment out the `Item.Link` field, I get different answers depending on the order of the `<link>` and `<atom:link>` elements.

Comment: You're right, the thing is, I don't need the `<atom:link>`, but when I uncomment these in the struct (http://play.golang.org/p/ucLx0-Kp2E), I get an empty string.

Comment: Right.  That seems to be another example of the bug: it is probably selecting the contents of the <atom:link> element, which is empty.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'll try and fix it, thank you! Answer the question and I'll mark it answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace handling in the standard library `encoding/xml` package seems to be a big ad-hoc, and having elements in different namespaces with the same name seems to be a trigger.

Ideally you'd be able to decode the given XML into the following structures:

```
type Rss struct {
    Items []Item `xml:"channel>item"`
}

type Item struct {
    Link     string   `xml:"link"`
    AtomLink AtomLink `xml:"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom link"`
}

type AtomLink struct {
    Href string `xml:"href,attr"`
}
```

But this results in the error `main.Item field "Link" with tag "link" conflicts with field "AtomLink" with tag "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom link"` (as seen in http://play.golang.org/p/LgW-vm4euL).

However, if we decide that we want to ignore the `<atom:link>` element by commenting out the `Item.AtomLink` field, we end up decoding an empty string, since `xml:"link"` matches `<link>` elements in any namespace rather than just the blank namespace.  The final `<atom:link>` element is empty, so doesn't return anything.

A couple of possible work arounds include:

1. Only try to decode the `<atom:link>` element, since it can be selected uniquely.  This may not be useful if you're also processing RSS feeds without Atom namespace elements.
2. Collect the contents of all `<link>` elements by modifying the `Item` struct to use:

   ```
   Links []string `xml:"link"`
   ```

   And then discard any empty strings in the slice.

At the end of the day, the package will need some way to refer to the blank namespace.  That may require new syntax in order to keep existing programs functioning though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll work around with this: http://play.golang.org/p/te2UatlMeL